# Why does Google Cloud Storage not send correct cache headers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have some images in Google Cloud Storage that I want to cache through the standard browser cache. So, in file object metadata field I wrote:

`Cache-control : public, max-age=300, no-transform`.

But when I get the image by generated URL the cache header reads:

`cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate`.

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

[Headers from browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUqro.png)

[Metadata form in Google Cloud Storage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROI3F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve the problem. 
Google object has 2 links for access. The correct link you may see on the screenshot. Previously, I use the link on "link URL" section.

Difference between two links it is a request server:

- Link with applying metadata get data from https://storage.googleapis.com/
- Link with no caching get data from https://storage.cloud.google.com/

I confused, but I don't observe little link button, so close to the big "link URL".

[image: correct url screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Only objects that are public can be cached as also stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control):

> Cache-Control only applies to objects with a public-read ACL.
>   **Non-public data are not cacheable.**

You are able to set the Cache-Control metadata even if the object is not public, but it will have no effect.

Comment: My object was public, but I was using the wrong link.