# Google Cloud Storage cache-control directive not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cache-control

I have a private bucket, but I want to override the metadata for the `Cache-Control` directive to be public. In the dashboard I have added `public, max-age=31536000` to the metadata of my object.

Upon requesting the object, I see that the cache-control is still set to:
`cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate`

Is there a way to override this? Otherwise, CDN will never cache private objects, resulting is frequent reads from my storage layer.

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Please check

Answer (score -1):

Cache-Control can only be set to public on publicly readable objects.So,only objects that are public can be cached. You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching#built-in_caching_for)

You are able to set the Cache-Control metadata even if the object is not public, but it will have no effect.

You can also check this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701402/18265638)

Comment: I was able to override this behavior by setting the cacheByStatus directive on Cloudflare. This enables caching, but it would revalidate on each request. I didn't take it a step further to prevent revalidation, but for those reading, it's possible to cache private assets despite the literature saying otherwise.

Comment: Have you gone through this [document](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/cache-control/#edge-cache-ttl)

Comment: Doesn't work on a public object either.